# useState Hook Renders entire component on setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, state

In the below code, I have used 2 "useState" hooks. Whenever I call the "setState" function of any one of these hooks, the whole component is re-rendered(Check "console.log" statements). I want if I call "setState" for one variable, only the element associated with that variable should render, rather the entire component

Code Snippet:

```
const App = () => {

  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const [count2, setCount2] = React.useState(0)

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCount(count => count + 1)}>
        {console.log('Counter 1')}
        <Text>{count}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCount2(count2 => count2 + 1)}>
        {console.log('Counter 2')}
        <Text>{count2}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo  - use useMemo

Comment: @AbuDujanaMahalail, Can u please explain it a bit more. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Render each `Text` in a stand-alone component ... This way whenever each `Counter` component receives a new-prop .. it will re-render.

```
 function FirstCounter ({ count }) {
  console.log('FirstCounter', count);
  return (  
    <Text>{count}</Text>
  );
}

export default React.memo(FirstCounter);

function SecondCounter ({ count }) {
  console.log('SecondCounter', count);
  return (  
    <Text>{count}</Text>
  );
}

export default React.memo(SecondCounter);

function App() {
  /** state is it was */
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const [count2, setCount2] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCount(count => count + 1)}>
        <FirstCounter count={count} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCount2(count2 => count2 + 1)}>
        <SecondCounter count={count2} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Comment: where is the state stored in you answer? Also, the components will re-render as their parent component rendered

Comment: @thedude I see it is React.memo there, so child componenets will be re-rendered only if props are changed